# Taking over a ship without killing everyone or damaging the ship?

Tags: spaceships

So, on the planet Anarkos, in the Yucleon sector of the galaxy, the Anarchist terrorists have set up their community, away from all governments that would enforce rules on them, like the Empire and UTF. The community is small, about 50,000 people (only about 30,000 ***actually*** want to be there.) A large portion of the population are permanently indentured servants, or slaves, captured form passing space ships and cargo freighters. They transport members on board, and capture them. The ship is brought back to the planet Anarkos, were it is scrapped for metal, and its crew are all enslaved. The weapons and advanced technology are kept by the community. The members have to capture the ship without killing or permanently harming any crew members, and without damaging any parts of the ship. How could they go about this?

Comment: Teleporting commandos can teleport precisely to have every crew member in a headlock. This is your universe and your rules.

Comment: Why not teleport people off?

Comment: @Michael Kutz: I’m sorry my English is bad. I meant transport

Comment: "Transporters" in Star Trek teleport people.  Perhaps change it to the Anarchists board the ships and capture the crew members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling a spaceship while leaving it repairable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84698/disabling-a-spaceship-while-leaving-it-repairable)

Comment: Anarchists tend to be quite opposed to slavery on principle. Perhaps that label is a mistranslation also?

Comment: user535733: They are ***Permanently Indentured Servants***. These Anarchist mostly capture government ships, which they see as slave ships

Comment: If the government ships are slave ships, their occupants would likely willingly go with them, once freed.

Comment: Anarchists also generally don't agree with misrepresentation about slavery as some kind of "Indenture". Real Indenture is a contract: Freely entered into, and with a limited term. You might consider changing the Pirate Planet's name to avoid confusing your readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already answered a quite similar question: [Disabling a spaceship while leaving it repairable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/84698/35041).

This [is my answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/85307/35041). Here I'll only write a small summary of my ideas:

- **Remote Hacking:** Self-explanatory. Hack the ship's systems from far away.
- **Electromagnetic Countermeasures:** There are several ways. Note that if you don't like the idea of a EMP beam you could instead launch an swarm of small drones, each one producing an EMP around the target.

  - **Slowly increase the EMP:** The enemy will have to choose between turn off the ship and surrender, or let it on and burn their circuits due to the electromagnetic pulse.
  - **Blind the ship sensors:** Like blinding a camera with a flashlight, you can blind their sensos with and EMP. They wouldn't know what to do, since tactical maneuvers are difficult without realtime data.
  - **Increase static energy:** Using gamma rays (I don't know if this is possible in real life) or some made-up technology, increase the static energy of the ship's hull, **that** is a real problem in spaceships. If the ship doesn't discharge the energy, either the crew will die from the shock or the systems will get burned.
- **Drone Brake:** A really big ship could lauch hundred of drones towards the enemy. They'll attach to the enemy armor (by steel ropes or hooks) accelerate in the opposite of the ship's direction, slowing down it. Note that this needs a lot of drones and fuel/energy for each drone.
- **Ship Rope Tying:** Instead of launch drones you could lauch steel ropes and hooks from the main ship to use it main engine in order to slowdown the enemy. Also you could use magnetic beams.
- **Destroy the Thrusters:** If the enemy ship has ion-thrusters, EM thrusters, gravitional drives or something like that, you can shoot their thrusters. I don't think they will blow up, right?
- **Heat Laser:** In space things doesn't cool down easy, so a heat beam that can heat up a ship could be useful. If the ship reaches a critical temperature, the fusion reactor would turn off to avoid explode. If that's not an issue, keeping the crew from dying of hyperthermia will be.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question

"They teleport members on board, and capture them"

If they have the ability to teleport on board then they have the ability to teleport people off.

Teleport the crew, in one go, from their ship to holding cells while teleporting your own crew on board.

Crew captured safely and ship undamaged.

Comment: I meant they transport not teleport. Confused the meaning of the two words

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping gas, stun guns, force fields, nets, goo, or any other non-lethal method.  Anything that can incapacitate the crew and they cannot defend against.